# Reload spell checking of UWP RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `RichEditBox` and a `ToggleButton`, which toggles the spell checking of the `RichEditBox`. By default, the spell checking is disabled. Therefore, when I type some nonsense in the editor, of course, it isn't underlined red. When I toggle the button after that, and insert some more rubbish characters, only the newly inserted stuff is marked as wrong, but not the characters inserted before enabling the spell checking.

Hence I'm looking for a possibility to "reload" the spell checking, so that the complete content of the `RichEditBox` is checked.

---

**My issue in pictures:**

Step 1: Inserting some random rubbish with disabled spellchecking

[[image]]

Step 2: Enabling spellchecking and typing the same characters again:

[[image]]

---

```
<Page
    x:Class="FontSizeTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FontSizeTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="SpellCheckingButton" Grid.Row="0" Checked="HandleSpellCheckingButton_Checked">Spell Checking</ToggleButton>
        <RichEditBox x:Name="Editor" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1"></RichEditBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>



public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HandleSpellCheckingButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        bool isChecked = ((ToggleButton) sender).IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
        Editor.IsSpellCheckEnabled = isChecked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Reload spell checking of UWP RichEditBox

The problem is `Checked` event only occurs in `ToggleButton` checked state, you just set Editor.IsSpellCheckEnabled as true but have not edit it back to false when `ToggleButton` uncheck state. We suggest you modify IsSpellCheckEnabled property in ToggleButton click event like the following.

```
private void SpellCheckingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isChecked = ((ToggleButton)sender).IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
    Editor.IsSpellCheckEnabled = isChecked;
}
```

**xaml**

```
<ToggleButton
    x:Name="SpellCheckingButton"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Click="SpellCheckingButton_Click"  
    >
    Spell Checking
</ToggleButton>
```

**Update**

> When I toggle the button after that, and insert some more rubbish characters, only the newly inserted stuff is marked as wrong, but not the characters inserted before enabling the spell checking.

I misunderstand your question, it's by default. If you want to re-check all the content, we need re-set the content like the following.

```
private void SpellCheckingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isChecked = ((ToggleButton)sender).IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
    Editor.IsSpellCheckEnabled = isChecked;
    var temp = string.Empty;
    Editor.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out temp);
    Editor.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, string.Empty);
    Editor.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, temp);
}
```

Comment: Oops :D. Yes, indeed I have used the wrong event. But my issue is still there, since in the steps in my question, I don't have unchecked the toggle button.

Comment: But in my example above I haven't unchecked the toggle button. By default, spell checking is disabled due to the `IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"`. When I click the button, spell checking is enabled, no matter if I use `Click` or `Checked`. My issue then is that the text typed before spell checking has been enabled is not reviewed. I don't even have tried to disable spell checking again.

Comment: I have updated case reply, sorry for misunderstanding your  problem.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your answer. I already have tried that, unfortunately, this solution didn't work for me. Other problems with it would be that this action would appear in the undo history of the `RichEditBox`, and that a new line is added in the `RichEditBox`.

Comment: For my testing, if we enable IsSpellCheckEnabled property and reload the previous content the spellcheck will effect again (it works in my side). and it is inevitable that add new action in the undo history. I will share my code sample.

Comment: This sample code pleas [check](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SpellCheckTest).

Comment: And this is [screenshot](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AEDQF5JAU2Dltbg&cid=2BF3B25AD081C152&id=2BF3B25AD081C152%2117141&parId=2BF3B25AD081C152%216514&o=OneUp).

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer. I have cloned your repository and I experience similar behaviour. It's quite random, which words/lines are underlined when you toggle the button. Is there no possibility to initiate a full spell check?

Comment: Currently, UWP `RichEditBox` does not support full spell check. if you want this feature please feel free post the requirement with windows feed back hub app. And if above answer is helpful please consider accept it.